# Django webhook receiver

Tags: python, json, django

I built a web hook receiver that takes JSON and creates a model object. It works fine with JSON. But someone I am receiving data from uses a different type of string data.
I am currently just printing it out in the console. How would I convert this into a model object?

The data they are sending looks like this:

Phone1=4441114444&FirstName=Chris&LastName=Farley&DOB=1982-11-21&Email=test@test.com

```
class Client(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(blank =True, max_length=100)
   last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default="", blank=True)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,default="", blank=True)


@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    print(json.loads(request.body)) 
    Client.objects.create(
       first_name=json.loads(request.body)['FirstName'], 
       last_name=json.loads(request.body)['LastName'],
       phone=json.loads(request.body)['Phone1'],
       email=json.loads(request.body)['Email']
       
       )


    return HttpResponse(request.body, status=200)
```

Comment: You should define in which format users must send you a data. If it's in a proper way then accept data, create instance and return 200, otherwise return 400. And look at `django-rest-framework` for creating such views

Comment: @Nikita: this is how HTML form data is encoded (so by the browser that uses a `<form>`).

Answer (score 1):

You access this with `request.POST`, so:

```
def webhook(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    Client.objects.create(
       first_name=request.POST['FirstName'], 
       last_name=request.POST['LastName'],
       phone=request.POST['Phone1'],
       email=request.POST['Email']
   )
    return HttpResponse(request.body, status=200)
```

But usually it is better to process data with [*forms* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/): these can perform validation, cleaning, and a `ModelForm` can save this to a model object in the database.

Comment: This solution is not working for me is there any way that I can decode the HTML and covert to JSON?

Comment: @Danny: exactly what problem does arise?

Comment: I get MultiValueDictKeyError: 'Phone1'

Comment: @Danny: that means that `Phone1` is not in the request, so not in the `<form>` you submit.

Comment: Is there a way I can covert the post to json?

Comment: @Danny: converting it to JSON would exactly produce the *same* problem, since the key is simply missing.